# A raceway problem

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, real-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control

Let $f(x)=\sin x$, and $g(x)=\sin x + 1$. Consider a set 
$S=\{(x,y)| f(x)\leq y \leq g(x), x\in [0,2\pi]\}$. This set $S$ can be considered as "Raceway"
My question is finding the shortest path in $S$ such that initial point lies in $\{0\}\times [0,1]$, and the terminal point lies in $\{2\pi\}\times [0,1]$.

Comment: Could you say a little bit more about where the problem comes from? What's the shortest length that you have been able to obtain?


Comment: (It is clear what to do for $0\leq x\leq \pi/2$ and $3\pi/2\leq 2\pi$, and there is a natural guess for what to do for $\pi/2\leqx\leq 3\pi/2$, but without checking or thinking further it's not clear to me how to prove that patching together these three paths gives a global minimum for the total path length.)

Comment: If you try to "peel" the middle section away from the sine curve, I think you will find the x coordinate goes away from the outer sections (because of the slope of the tangent being negative).  While I am not willing to do the arithmetic, I think a global minimum follows from Yemon's hints and mine.  Also, this is more appropriate for math.stackexchange.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.02.14

Comment: Gerhard, I am not so sure it belongs better on MSE, my feeling is that there it would attract many eager but incomplete answers.

Comment: Yemon, perhaps so. I still have the feeling that this could be (or was) posed as a homework problem in an advanced high school calculus course.  ArtofProblemSolving website then?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.02.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an illustration of the question:

        [image: Sine Track]

Comment: Although one could have a shorter path by going from $(0,0)$ to $(\pi/2,0).$ and  from $(3\pi/2,0)$ to $(2\pi,0).$ The middle linear segment might go from approximately $(1/2+0.117)\pi$ to $(3/2-0.117)\pi.$ It seems obvious that anything differing from this can be made shorter.

Comment: @Aaron: I interpreted the question (perhaps incorrectly) as having a given point specified within the possible start interval, and a given point specified within the possible termination interval.  But I can see another interpretation is to minimize over all starting and ending points.

Comment: @Joseph: Thank you for posting picture to my problem. I originally thought about this problem long ago, and I thought straight line segments for $[0,\pi/2]$, and $[3\pi/2,2\pi]$, and a sine curve in the middle section would be shortest, but I am not sure that it is the shortest one. 

Comment: Ah, so I did misinterpret the problem as starting and ending anywhere on those vertical segments.  As Aaron says, those three straight segment tangents plus a portion of the curves is clearly the shortest.  And starting anywhere is just a small variation: the middle segment is the same, and the two end segments are tangents as illustrated.